# My question is that why converse need not be true?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The homomorphic   image  of ring with  unity  is  a   ring with unity    but  converse  need not be true .

My question is that why converse need not  be true  ?

I mean

## If $R '$ is a  homomorphics  image of a ring $R$  where $R'$ is  a  ring with unity then$ R$ need   not have   unity

As i know  that The homomorphic   image  of ring with  unity  is  a   ring with unity take  $f : \mathbb{Z_2}  \rightarrow  \mathbb{Z_2}$

Any hints/solution

thanks u

Comment: The converse is what?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by the converse? There are a couple of different ways to state this as an implication, but these statements do not have the same converses.

Comment: There are many things to convert here. For instance, do you mean "given two rings with unity and a function between them, then even if the image is a ring the function isn't necessarily a homomorphism"?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft i have  edit its

Comment: @Wuestenfux i have  edit its

Comment: okks @Arthur let me think more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the homomorphism $f:\Bbb Z\to \Bbb Z\times2\Bbb Z$ given by $f(n)=(n,0)$. The image of $f$ is a unital ring (being isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$), but $\Bbb Z\times 2\Bbb Z$ is not unital.

Comment: superb  answer i gots its